# Why does CGFloat casted from Float not exhibit CGFloat behavior?

Tags: swift, casting, drawing

I have this simple example where I try to draw a circle. This code below does not give me a circle.

```
import UIKit

class PlayingCardView: UIView {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(){

            context.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, 
                           y: bounds.midY), radius: 100.0, 
                           startAngle: 0, 
                           endAngle: CGFloat(2.0*Float.pi), 
                           clockwise: true)

            context.setLineWidth(5.0)
            UIColor.red.setStroke()
            context.strokePath()
            print(2.0*CGFloat.pi)
            print(CGFloat(2.0*Float.pi))
        } 
    }
}
```

This [is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUcQi.png) with the above code:

with output:

`6.283185307179586 
6.283185005187988`

from the print statements which correspond to `2.0*CGFloat.pi` and `CGFloat(2.0*Float.pi)` respectively.

Updating the code to this (I only change the endAngle in `context.addArc` to be `2.0*CGFloat.pi` instead of `CGFloat(2.0*Float.pi)`

```
import UIKit

class PlayingCardView: UIView {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(){

            context.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, 
                           y: bounds.midY), radius: 100.0, 
                           startAngle: 0, 
                           endAngle: 2.0*CGFloat.pi, 
                           clockwise: true)

            context.setLineWidth(5.0)
            UIColor.red.setStroke()
            context.strokePath()
            print(2.0*CGFloat.pi)
            print(CGFloat(2.0*Float.pi))
        } 
    }
}
```

I get this [drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WR6jW.png) (The circle is there)

There is obviously a difference between the casted CGFloat from Float and CGFloat. Does anybody know what it is and why this behavior is useful in Swift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a 64-bit platform, `CGFloat` is (essentially) `Double`, a 64-bit floating point number, whereas `Float` is a 32-bit floating point number.

So `2.0*Float.pi` is “2π with 32-bit precision”, and converting that to the 64-bit quantity `CGFloat` preserves the value, without increasing the precision.

That is why `2.0*CGFloat.pi != CGFloat(2.0*Float.pi)`. The former is “2π with 64-bit precision”, and is what you should pass to the drawing functions.

In your particular case, `CGFloat(2.0*Float.pi)` is a tiny bit smaller than `2.0*CGFloat.pi`, so that only an invisibly short arc is drawn (from radians 0.0 to approximately -0.00000003).

For a *full circle* you can alternatively use

```
let radius: CGFloat = 100.0
context.addEllipse(in: CGRect(x: bounds.midX - radius, y: bounds.midY - radius,
                              width: 2.0 * radius, height: 2.0 * radius))
```

and avoid all rounding problems.